# Enable button not working

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to disable "Execute" button until submit button is clicked.
But after Submit button is clicked, "Execute" button should get enabled.

HTML -

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" >
  <span id="spryselect1">
       <label for="flow">Select  Flow</label>
          <select name="Select Flow" id="flow">
            <option id="sendmoney" value="sendmoney">A</option>
            <option id="sendmoneyp2p" value="sendmoneyp2p">Send Money P2P</option>
            <option id="sendmoneyservice">Send Money Service</option>
            <option id="econebay">Express Checkout - On eBay</option>
            <option id="ecoffebay">Express Checkout - Off eBay</option>
            <option id="gsp">Global Shipping Platform</option>
            <option id="pos">TouchStone POS</option>
            <option id="davisauthcapture">Davis Checkout - Auth &amp; Capture</option>
            <option id="davisfp">Davis Checkout - Forced Post</option>
          </select>


      <span id="sprytextfield1">
      <label>Stage Name
        <input type="text" name="stage" id="stage" />
        Buyer
      </label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span>
      <label>
        <select name="buyer" id="buyer">
          <option>US</option>
          <option>UK</option>
          <option>CA</option>
          <option>FR</option>
          <option>DE</option>
          <option>AU</option>
        </select>
        Seller
      </label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span>
      <label>
        <select name="buyer2" id="buyer2">
          <option>US</option>
          <option>UK</option>
          <option>CA</option>
          <option>FR</option>
          <option>DE</option>
          <option>AU</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
      <input name="SubmitID" type="submit" id="SubmitID" />
        <br />
        <br />
        Flow Description 
        <label for="Descrptn"></label>
        <textarea name="Descrptn" id="Descrptn" cols="45" rows="1"></textarea>
             <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Output
        <textarea name="output" cols="45" rows="5" readonly="readonly" id="output">Output here</textarea>
        <br />
        <br /> 
        <div align="center">
        <input type="button" name="submitbutton" id="executebutton" value="Execute Flow" action="checkState()"/>

        <input type="button" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton2" value="Contribute"/>
        </div>
        <br />
      </label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>
      </form>
```

JS-

```
document.getElementById("executebutton").disabled="true";
var button = document.getElementById("SubmitID");
function myfunc()
{
 document.getElementById("executebutton").disabled="false";   
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `myFunc()`? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: remove the quotes from the booleans

Answer (score 0):

The `true` and `false` are data types. Not strings.

```
document.getElementById("executebutton").disabled=true;
var button = document.getElementById("SubmitID");
function myfunc()
{
 document.getElementById("executebutton").disabled=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `disabled` attribute doesn't work like a boolean; if an element has a `disabled` attribute with any value, it will be disabled. To re-enable the button, remove the disabled attribute:

```
document.getElementById("executebutton").removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("executebutton").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("SubmitID").onclick =  function() {
    document.getElementById("executebutton").disabled = false;
};
```

There you go, tested myself. (http://jsfiddle.net/VZ3jw/)